# Constructive Insertion Sort

Tags: python, sorting, insertion-sort

I having trouble with insertion sort and I feel I might be missing the point of the sort and misunderstanding the fundamentals.

We were given a insertion sort which edited the array which was fed into it. We are tasked with then modifying the code we have been given to then create a constructive insertion sort which will not edit the original array

This is the code I have so far

```
def append(A, x):
    return A + [x] 

def insertionSort(A):
    B = []
    B = append(B, A[0])
    for i in range(1, len(A)):
        B = insert(B, A[i], i, A)
    return str(B)

def insert(B, k, hi, A):
    print(B, k, hi)
    for x in range(hi-1, -1, -1):
        if B[x] <= k:
            B = append(B, k)
            return B
        B = append(B, A[x])
    B[0] = k 
    return B

print(insertionSort([2,4,6,8,10,1,3,5,7,9]))
```

However after the third or forth element in the list it begins adding all the items to the end of the list in reverse order

```
[2] 4 1
[2, 4] 6 2
[2, 4, 6] 8 3
[2, 4, 6, 8] 10 4
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10] 1 5
[1, 4, 6, 8, 10, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2] 3 6
[1, 4, 6, 8, 10, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1, 10, 8, 6, 4, 3] 5 7
[1, 4, 6, 8, 10, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1, 10, 8, 6, 4, 3, 3, 1, 10, 8, 6, 5] 7 8
[1, 4, 6, 8, 10, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1, 10, 8, 6, 4, 3, 3, 1, 10, 8, 6, 5, 7] 9 9
[1, 4, 6, 8, 10, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1, 10, 8, 6, 4, 3, 3, 1, 10, 8, 6, 5, 7, 9]
```

I cannot wrap my head around why this is wrong.

Thanks dearly to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 3):

The reverse problem is at the foor loop in the insert function 
when your loop hit those values it starts the reverse mode

```
def insert(B, k, hi, A):
    # when hi=5
    for x in range(hi-1, -1, -1):
        # x = 4
        # here B[4] is 10 and k=1 so B[4] <= 1 is False
        # you program does not execute the inside of if
        # instead it jumps to B = append(B, A[x]) where A[4] == 10
        # and the this loop goes in reverse mode from 4 to 0
        # when x = 3
        # B[x] = 8 so 8 is not less or equal of k where k = 1
        # so it jumps again to B = append(B, A[x]) where A[x] = A[3] = 8
        # so it append 8 
        # and so on 
        # when this loop is finished your list will look like [1,4,6,8,10,10,8,6,4,2]
        # the 1 gets added when the loop is finished at B[0] = k 
        # and then rest of the outputs are result of the loop inside the insertionSort func
        if B[x] <= k:
            B = append(B, k)
            return B
        B = append(B, A[x])
    B[0] = k 
    return B
```

Here is a solution:

```
def insertionSort(A):
    copy_sort = A.copy()

    for i in range(1, len(copy_sort)):
        item = copy_sort[i]

        j = i - 1
        while j >= 0 and copy_sort[j] > item:
            copy_sort[j + 1] = copy_sort[j]
            j -= 1
        copy_sort[j + 1] = item

    return copy_sort


your_array = [2,4,6,8,10,1,3,5,7,9]
sorted = insertionSort(your_array)
print(your_array)
print(sorted)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to work out your algorithm on paper, and then translate those steps to Python code.  What you've implemented is convoluted and incorrect.

Most of all, `insert` is very confused as to the information it needs and how it should do its job.  As best I can see from your code, you want this routine to insert a given value `k` into the appropriate location in list `B`.  For some reason, you've also passed in list `A` and the value's location in that list, neither of which is applicable.

What your routine does then is strange; starting from the end of `B` (using `i` instead of `B` itself), the code checks the elements of B; every time it finds a value in the list less than the new one, it appends the new one to the end of `B`.  Regardless of that comparison, it appends the corresponding element of `A` to `B`.
Nowhere do you *insert* the element in the proper place.

Rewrite this code.  Start with the minimum necessary information:

```
def insert(arr, new_val):
# insert new_val into the list arr
```

Now, your function has two steps to carry out:

- Find the proper position for `new_val`
- Make a new list with the value inserted into that spot.

You return that new list.

Can you move on from there?